# Detect battery drain programmatically

Tags: android

I have some application where users usually spend quite long time every day and it does also some background work, notifications, alarms etc.
I want to be sure that it does not drain the battery too much after some new functionality added.

Is it possible to collect data of my app battery usage on users devices?

I know that some functionality was added since android 5.1 via ADB, but is it possible to do it programmatically?
Maybe some indirect way, like CPU time, active screen and wifi usage of my app?

Answer (score 2):

Not as Depp as you want, 
in fact you cannot know which app is draining the device battery, you can only have details about battery charge status.

The BatteryManager broadcasts all battery and charging details in a sticky Intent that includes the charging status.

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
```

You can extract both the current charging status and, if the device is being charged, whether it's charging via USB or AC charger:

```
// Are we charging / charged?
int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                     status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

// How are we charging?
int chargePlug = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
```

all details here: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Comment: Thanks, I found more useful `BatteryManager` methods `BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY` and `BATTERY_PROPERTY_CHARGE_COUNTER` which does not require broadcast receiver. But what I really want - that values from battery usage settings - `CPU total` and `Computed power use`